# Detect apps on my iphone without being rejected by Apple?

Tags: ios, ios-urlsheme

My app has been rejected by Apple for the following reason "Our team is aware that iHasApp is using publicly available APIs, however this specific implementation abuses canOpenURL: to detect all apps on a given device".So I start to look for another way to list all the installed app in the user's phone.So my questions are:

1/Are they some web apps which can detect the installed apps?

2/is it possible to detect apps using their icones?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I think the reason your app is being rejected is because it tries to detect other installed apps, not because it uses canOpenURL specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement a workaround, the chances are that Apple will still reject your app anyway.

Obtaining a list of applications installed on the phone is evidently disallowed. Apple has rejected apps using lots of methods to detect this:

- Your solution of "canOpenURL"
- This solution using private apis [List of all apps installed on iOS device and their position on the Home Screen (Springboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233458/916299)
- This (dated) answer using file path manipulation and private apis: [get list of installed applications on iphone objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8646080/916299)