# IOS get installed Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, installed-applications

I'm using this code to get installed apps in ios :

```
 ( NSArray * )installedApps{


NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
//  NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:@selector(allApplications)]);


return [workspace performSelector:@selector(allApplications)];

}
```

that works, but I want to know if it's allowed on Apple store, and its not using a private API

Comment: Hope this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614691/finding-list-of-installed-apps-on-iphone

Comment: This is a private API.  It is not permitted on the App Store

Comment: all depends on what you are doing with this private API... If you are not gonna harm, they will approve else they will not approve...

Comment: thank you for the answer , @fahim in which case for example  they will approve ?

Comment: can you tell me what you are gonna do by finding the names of the apps installed? all depend on what you are gonna do.... I used private API in many projects, but they never reject...

Comment: its to suggest new applications to the user ,  anyway  is there a way get the names of instaled applications in swift.

Comment: Yes, there must be....

Comment: Okay, if you are doing this, then Apple will approve. While submitting the app, let Apple know the code that you used as private API. When I use private API, I send my private API code to Apple and inform them what I am doing with that code. As they see I just use it for listing the app name, they will approve. If you mis-use private API, they will reject.

Comment: ah ok , cool . thank you